# RESTTemplate parameter String not being received

Tags: resttemplate

I have the below REST API:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "saveSetting", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody Boolean saveSetting(@RequestBody String settingXML) {

    //logs debug message
    logger.debug("saveSetting is executed!");

    Boolean success = false;

    System.out.println("xmlstring is " + settingXML);

    try {
        config.setSettings(null);
        success = Setting.saveSetting(settingXML, "C:\\Users\\hansa\\ConfigSetting.xml");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    logger.debug("saveSetting is returned");

    return success;
}
```

And my RESTTemplate code is below:

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

    MultiValueMap<String, String> parametersMap = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>();
    parametersMap.add("settingXML", stringXML);



    Boolean success = restTemplate.postForObject(serverURL, parametersMap, Boolean.class);
```

The API is called and response obtained with no exception. But, the string I sent as parameter is empty string. Any idea what I am doing wrong in sending the string over the call?

Comment: Finally, exchange worked.

Comment: `RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
  HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<>(new String(stringXML));
  ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate
    .exchange(serverURL, HttpMethod.POST, request, String.class);`